# Protocol error when executing cpp-driver datastax

Tags: c, cassandra, datastax

I am currently workinig on datastax cpp-driver in C and was working around some examples when I came across a very trivial problem. While trying to execute the [Basic Authentication Script](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/examples/auth/auth.c) here, I found this error showing up and the code execution getting stuck.

**The Error:**

```
1587040775.210 [ERROR] (cluster_connector.cpp:192:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Unable to establish a control connection to host 127.0.0.3 because of the following error: Underlying connection error: Connect error 'connection refused'
1587040775.210 [ERROR] (cluster_connector.cpp:192:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Unable to establish a control connection to host 127.0.0.2 because of the following error: Underlying connection error: Connect error 'connection refused'
1587040775.211 [ERROR] (cluster_connector.cpp:192:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Unable to establish a control connection to host 127.0.0.1 because of the following error: Underlying connection error: Received error response 'Invalid or unsupported protocol version (66); supported versions are (3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta)' (0x0200000A)
1587040775.211 [WARN] (cluster_connector.cpp:289:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Host 127.0.0.1 does not support protocol version DSEv2. Trying protocol version DSEv1...
1587040775.212 [ERROR] (cluster_connector.cpp:192:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Unable to establish a control connection to host 127.0.0.1 because of the following error: Underlying connection error: Received error response 'Invalid or unsupported protocol version (65); supported versions are (3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta)' (0x0200000A)
1587040775.212 [WARN] (cluster_connector.cpp:289:void datastax::internal::core::ClusterConnector::on_connect(datastax::internal::core::ControlConnector*)): Host 127.0.0.1 does not support protocol version DSEv1. Trying protocol version v4...
```

What could be these protocols that are not supported by my machine? Also, after it comes to the last warning, which is `trying protocol v4` it gets stuck.
I'm using Casssandra 3.10+, Cpp-driver 2.13.

Anybody with a workaround or a solution would be of much help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message seems to be verbose and sequential enough (`Unable to establish a control connection to host 127.0.0.3 because of the following error: Underlying connection error: Connect error 'connection refused'` that a literal interpretation would be that you are failing to connect.  make sure you are referencing the right address, and passing the correct credentials, and have sufficient privilege to get a connection.

Comment: @ryyker ok, so looks like we're in a iffy here. I've provided the link to the script used. As you can see, it is already using localhost to connect on. Which is exactly what I am doing. Also, the credentials are correct and so is everything. I'm guessing you did not read the whole error. It later says that there's an unsupported protocol issue here. To a host which did not refuse connection aka `127.0.0.1`. I wouldn't have written a trivial error and protocol error in the heading if connection refused had been my problem, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked around a bunch to find some documentation to back this up but I can't find any, so this part is conjecture. It appears that server version 3 uses protocol V3. It looks like server version 4 (still in beta) will use protocol V4. I suspect V5 is a future iteration that is being planned and still not written in stone yet (and why it's tagged as beta in the warning).

This part isn't conjecture.
If you add this to your code before you connect to the cluster:

```
cass_cluster_set_protocol_version(cluster, CASS_PROTOCOL_VERSION_V3);
```

All the warnings about downgrading to different protocols should go away.

Comment: It works! It seems by default the driver uses
CASS_PROTOCOL_VERSION_DSEV1 = 0x41  and
CASS_PROTOCOL_VERSION_DSEV2 = 0x42
which is: "Only supported when using the DSE driver with DataStax Enterprise"